# Como eu posso apresentar em minutos:segundos o valor de um ToolTip que é dado em segundos?

Tags: javascript, c#, view, highcharts, tooltip

O valor da série Y é dado em segundos, mas preciso apresentar no tooltip em minutos:segundos.
Exemplo: Valor em segundos= 320. Valor a ser apresentado no tooltip= 05:20.

Eu fiz um script para mudar o formato, calculando o quociente e resto, transformando para string e passando para o tooptip, mas o resultado é sempre NaN.
Como eu poderia formatar esse valor para apresentar no **tooltip** os 05:20?

Minha aplicação é c# com padrão MVC. Os gráficos são renderizados pelo Highcharts.

```
@{var chartOptions4 = new Highcharts
                    {
                        Title = new Title
                        {
                            Text = "Setting Time"
                        },
                        XAxis = new List<XAxis>
                            {
                            new XAxis
                            {
                                Categories = ViewData["datas_saida_resf_prod"] as List<string>
                            }
                        },
                        YAxis = new List<YAxis>
                        {
                            new YAxis
                            {
                                Labels = new YAxisLabels
                                {
                                    Formatter = "formatYAxis1"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Tooltip = new Tooltip
                        {
                            HeaderFormat = "<b>{point.x}</b><br>",
                            PointFormatter = "formatToolTip"
                        },
                        Series = new List<Series>
                        {
                            new LineSeries
                            {
                                Name = "Normal T.I.",
                                Data = @ViewData["lista_normalTI"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                            },
                            new LineSeries
                            {
                                Name = "Normal T.F.",
                                Data = @ViewData["lista_normalTF"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                            },
                            new LineSeries
                            {
                                Name = "Moído T.I.",
                                Data = @ViewData["lista_moidoTI"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                            },
                            new LineSeries
                            {
                                Name = "Moído T.F.",
                                Data = @ViewData["lista_moidoTF"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              }
                    };
                    chartOptions4.ID = "chart4";
                    var renderer4 = new HighchartsRenderer(chartOptions4);
                    }

                    @Html.Raw(renderer4.RenderHtml())
```

Script:

```
 function formatToolTip() {
            var quociente, resto;
            quociente = Math.floor((this.value / 60), 0);
            resto = Math.round(((this.value / 60) - quociente) * 60);
            var valor = (Math.floor((this.value / 60), 0)).toString() + ":" + (Math.round(((this.value / 60) - quociente) * 60)).toString();

            var result = this.series.name + ':' + valor;
            return result;
        }
```

O resultado desse código é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: por que você já não passa essa informação formatada? a sua dúvida é sobre javascript ou C#?

Comment: Porque, até onde eu sei, o LineSeriesData só aceita o valor double.

Comment: Por isso pensei em formatar no javascript mesmo

Answer (score -2):

Era só usar `this.y` no lugar de `this.value`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado, eu não tinha percebido que ao escolher uma sinalização automaticamente era feito um comentário rs